# What are the consequences of stealing in Avadon: The Black Fortress?

Tags: avadon-the-black-fortress

I've encountered some items marked as "NY" (Not Yours), and I'm wondering what the consequences are if I try to steal them. Can I steal without consequence like in many RPGs, or are there repercussions if I do that?

Comment: I haven't tested in Avadon, but in early Spiderweb titles, such as Blades of Exile, stealing in town within the vision of a citizen results in the town guards coming for your blood (and usually getting it). Stealing with no witnesses had no in-game consequences, even in cases where you break into the captain's locked quarters, close the door, steal everything in the room, open the door, and exit in full view of the captain himself from his formerly locked office.

Answer (score 1):

In Avadon, it seems that it never hurts to try to take something that is Not Yours. If somebody can see you, the game won't let you take it; and if nobody can see you, than taking it will have no consequences.

This topic is discussed here: http://spiderwebforums.ipbhost.com/index.php?/topic/16193-items-that-are-ny/